# How to create a customizable dashboard by letting the user add and remove the widgets?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, widget

I'm trying to build a dashboard with customize-able functionalities such as adjusting different `<div>`, dragging and dropping different `<div>`, adding different `<div>` and thereby remembering the position where the `<div>` are being placed. This dashboard is similar to [iGoogle's Dashboard](http://www.google.co.in/ig).

**Question 1)** If I'm not wrong, these `<div>` are called widgets. Are they?

I've gone through the web regarding this, and found most of the tutorials/links for inheriting already built widgets from some external source to your webpage, but this is not what I want. I want to build my own widgets(For eg:- representing some JSON data in pie chart can be one widget and representing the same data in bar graph can be another). So, my next question is :-

**Question 2)** I'll be having a separate url for letting the user choose widgets according to his needs. So, do I keep the `<div>` for every widget hidden at the initial time and un-hide them when the user enables them or is there some other way of doing it? 
PS: There's surely some other way because on going through iGoogle's source code, they add it after the user has enabled that widget. So how is that done?

**Question 3)** How the placement of `<div>` can be saved?

Comment: Remember to at least only hide widgets that they're allowed to have

Comment: I didnt get you. Can you please be more elaborative?

Comment: I'm referring to question **2**. Just a minor warning

Comment: Ohh Nice catch. Didnt thought of that.Thanks. Do you know is there any other method of adding/removing widgets,thereby allowing the user to customize his/her dashboard according to his needs because this method of hiding `<div>` doesnt seems logical enough?

Comment: I haven't done anything similar before, but I think you want to keep most of your logic on a server. You could, for example, keep a list of widgets in a user profile table, and then let the server respond with the corresponding divs. The keyword here is _server_ anyway :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1)**
Yes, they can be known as widgets.  Quite a few Javascript frameworks, such as jQuery UI, include functionality to move elements, snap them to grids etc - http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to

**Question 2)**
I would only load the widgets depending on what the user has chosen / is allowed to see, otherwise all widgets would be on the page, just hidden - users could then unhide these widgets, allowing them to see things they might not have access to.

You could load the widgets onto the page in many different ways.  One way would be to find out what widgets the user has chosen when the page loads, via server side (PHP etc), and load those widgets in before the user sees the page.  Or via Ajax which would allow you to load the page, then the widgets could be added to the page afterwards - this could be useful if you want to animate the widgets onto the page, or if there's a lot of data on the widget which could mean it takes a while to load in.

**Question 3)**
Using my example in Q1, you could capture the X, Y co-ordinates when the user drops the div, and use Ajax to fire those to the server, then store these co-ordinates against that user's widget.  When the user next loads the page, you use these co-ordinates to load the widget into the correct place.

Comment: In Q2) So when new widgets will be added, do I dynamically create the divs? If yes, then if I'm not wrong upon refreshing those divs will be destroyed. Arnt they?

Comment: in Q3) the co-ordinates can be calculated. Ok .Fine. So, like this if any change in the positioning of any widget, I have to calculate the co-ordinates of every widget(div), which i guess is not logical because I dont know co-ordinates of which all divs do I have to calculate. I mean there will be a lot of divs. So out of those how will I get to know which are widget divs and which are not?

Comment: I think I got the solution for Q3). I'll be storing the ids of widgets which are there on the dashboard and then calculating the position cooordinates of only those divs which are there in the DB and respectively storing the position co-ordinates alongside the div-ids in a key value pair. Isnt it?

Comment: Q2) Yes, you would dynamically create the divs.  On refreshing the page, it will just run the same server side / client side script that runs when you first load the page, so the widgets will just be recreated.

Q3) Yes, you could store the co-ordinatess against the widget ID for that user, which you would update via Ajax when they 'drop' the widget after dragging it.